# Two forms with multiple submit buttons in single PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to write a dynamic form using PHP. I'd like to have a single webpage that contains two forms:

1. The upper form allows to search for an element in the mysql database, e.g., for a name
2. The lower form shows the data that is associated with this name in the database

If I press on the "Search" button of the upper form, then the the lower form is shown and the text fields are filled with data from the database that belong to this name. If I change the user name to some other value and press again "Search", then the data that is associated with the new record is shown and so on.

The lower form also has a button "Update" which allows to transfer changes made to the text boxes (in the lower part) to the database.

Now, I have the following problem: In my script I set initially the value of name (from the upper form) to "". When I then press the "Search" button, then the lower part of the form is shown and the corresponding data is shown in the lower part. When I then press the "Update" button, then the text field associated with name is set to the empty string. This is because in my script I set initially name to the "". I'd like that in this case the data entered in the upper form is not changed, i.e., it stays the same.

I guess, I am missing something here. There is probably an easy solution for this and I am doing something fundamentally wrong. It'd be great if you could help me.

That's what I tried... I deleted lots of details, but I guess that can give you an idea what I am trying to do. Notice that the whole code is in the file update.php.

```
<?php
function search_bus($mysql, $name)
{
 // do some stuff here...
}

function update_bus($mysql, $b_id)
{
    // do some stuff here...
}

// some global variables
$b_id = 0;
$username = ""; // username of business

// get b_id that corresponds to username
if (isset($_REQUEST['search']))
{
    $b_id =0; // business id
    if (isset($_POST['user']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $b_id = search_bus($mysql, $username);
    }
}
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
{
    update_bus($mysql, $b_id);
}


?>

<h2>Search:</h2> 
<form name="search_bus" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="<?= htmlentities($username) ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Suchen" name="search"/>
</form>

<?php 
if($b_id != 0) 
{
?>

<h2>Data:</h2> 
<form name="business_design" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<-- some form follows here -->

<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?  If you are dynamically hiding, you will need to have some javascript or a javascript library (Like jQuery).

Comment: I added some code... Hope that helps!

Comment: No :) It's my first script in PHP. I am coming from C++ programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're missing is to create a HTML Hidden field to keep the value of Name variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php print $nameVar ?>" />
```

Add this input to both forms so you can keep the value no matter what button the user clicks.

Hope this helps.

Adding code to verify the

```
<h2>Search:</h2>  
<form name="search_bus" method="post" 
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" value="<?= htmlentities($username) ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<?php print $b_id?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Suchen" name="search"/> 
</form>  


<?php  if($b_id != 0)  { ?>  
<h2>Data:</h2>  
<form name="business_design" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];>">      
<input type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<?php print $b_id?>" />
<-- some form follows here -->  
<?php  } ?> 

Dont initialize $b_id if it already comes into the http request.
if (!isset($_POST['b_id']))
{
 $b_id = 0; 
}          
else
{
 $b_id = $_POST['b_id'];
}
```

This way you can alway remember the last selected value of b_id.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Not sure I understand... what shall I put in this hidden field? The b_id? But then how is it initialize to zero and how is it collected from the DB depending on the name that has been entered in the username text field?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work :(. I guess, I am missunderstanding something. I think my problems is that essentatially, when I press the button of the second form, then the $b_id=0 and the lower form is not shown as it is only displayed when $b_id != 0... somehow I have to ensure that when I press the submit button of the lower form, that then the $b_id value is NOT set to 0. Any idea how to achieve this? Many thanks!!

Comment: I would do something like this:

Comment: I edited my answer, i set 2 diferent hidden fields into both forms this way doesn't matter what button form the user click b_id will keep the b_id value, then you catch it and set the same variable with the new value.

Comment: Btw, if you need to ensure $b_id != 0 you can user JavaScript, once you have created your hidden fields them contains the value of b_id, so you can use JS getElementById (Set an ID to these fields first) and validate they contain the value you need. Find how to use it at: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/getelementbyid-form.phtml